# Java TimSort throws IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, sorting, illegalargumentexception

This does not seem to be the same as any of the other Java sort exception issues already brought up.  Using Java SE 8.  My comparator:

```
@Override
public int compare (BusinessObject bo1, BusinessObject bo2) {
  int scoreComp = Double.compare(bo1.getScore(), bo2.getScore());
  if (scoreComp != 0) {
    return(scoreComp);
  }
  String name1 = bo1.getName() == null ? "" : bo1.getName();
  String name2 = bo2.getName() == null ? "" : bo2.getName();
  return(name1.compareTo(name2));
}
```

When I run this on lists of 10,000 or so objects, it throws the IllegalArgumentException about 25% of the time.  If I rerun it on the same data, it sometimes does not throw the exception.  I don't see any transitivity issues or NaN issues.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is BusinessObject mutable? Is it possible any of the instances are being mutated during the sort?

Comment: It is mutable, but there aren't any other threads running during my sort.  The getter for score turns out to be too complex, though, and there may be a chance that two calls to it will return different values over time.  I am simply a consumer of BusinessObject, so I can't really alter it, but I can try to wrap it and freeze the score before sorting.

Comment: "there may be a chance that two calls to it will return different values over time" this makes the object impossible to "compare", as it violates the contract of compare since multiple calls of compare for the same objects may return different values over time.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't been aware of this possiblity until I pestered the creator of BusinessObject.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but in java 8, there are methods on [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to simply creating compound Camparator implementations. For example, what you are trying to do would look like this:

```
Comparator.comparingDouble(BusinessObject::getScore)
          .thenComparing(
               Comparator.nullsFirst(
                   Comparator.comparing(BusinessObject::getName));
```